# All my data is located on Macintosh HD while Macintosh HD - Data is empty

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have recently noticed that on my 2019 MacBook Pro running Big Sur (11.4) all files including applications, user data, desktop folder, etc. are located on Macintosh HD. Everything works fine, but AFAIK my user data should be on Macintosh - Data. Everything works but should I do something about this?

I first noticed this when I first set up a Time Machine drive. Time Machine was complaining about Macintosh HD and I needed to unmount it for the backup to start.

A few weeks ago I wiped this Mac as I got it from a colleague. I followed some guide online to reinstall the OS.

Any advise would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's the output of `diskutil list`. It looks like there are two Macintosh HD - Data volumes. I also took a look into Disk Utility (which I guess I should have done sooner) to find that there are in fact two Volumes called Macintosh HD - Data in there. I suppose I could safely remove the empty one then? [image: Disk Utility]

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     1.6 MB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.3 GB    disk1s2
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s2s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 284.3 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.9 MB   disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
   7:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     34.4 GB    disk1s7
```

Comment: Please post the results of typing `diskutil list` in Terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove the empty one. It will not allow you to remove it if it's the one you're currently booted from.

The correct one should also show an OS version – not just "APFS Data Volume"